# Menu secondary tabs

Tags: 7, routes

How do I create secondary local tasks with hook_menu in Drupal 7?

For instance, if I wanted to add a new tab to a node, that presented multiple tasks beneath it?

- View
- Edit
- Update

  - Price
  - Photo
  - Person

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use a combination of the [`MENU_LOCAL_TASK`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/constant/MENU_LOCAL_TASK/7) and [`MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/constant/MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK/7) types:

```
 $items['node/%node/update'] = array(
   'title' => 'Update',
   'page callback' => 'price_callback_function',
   'access arguments' => array('access args'),
   'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK // This adds the 'Update' tab to the node path
 );

 $items['node/%node/update/price'] = array(
   'title' => 'Price',
   'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
   'weight' => -10
 );

 $items['node/%node/update/photo'] = array(
   'title' => 'Photo',
   'page callback' => 'callback_function',
   'access arguments' => array('access args'),
   'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK // This adds another tab under 'Update'
 );

// etc...
```

You can control the order of the tab using the `weight` key in your menu item.

Don't forget to clear Drupal's cache once you add this to `hook_menu()`

Comment: Ok, so this cascades into secondary tabs? I thought I had tried this but didn't see a result. I will try again.

Comment: @Kevin I've updated the answer to something that will probably work a bit better, it sets the 'Update' tab to use the callback for the price page (as Price will be the default tab anyway) and actually creates that default tab with the second item. Descendant paths inherit the attributes of their parent(s) so you don't need to set the callback etc for the second item