# Secondary Tabs and views

Tags: routes

I am trying to get Secondary Tabs to work. I want to create a local tab with sub tabs.

View | Edit | **Reg Report**

Reg Report 
       Reg Report | Pre-Registration | Post-Registartion (Secondary Tabs)

I tried this method ([Menu secondary tabs](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/20904/menu-secondary-tabs)) and have it showing the naviagation, however when I add the path for Photo to my second view the navigation goes away.

Here is the code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function secondary_tabs_menu() {
  $items['node/%node/update'] = array(
   'title' => 'Update',
   'page callback' => 'price_callback_function',
   'access arguments' => array('access args'),
   'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK // This adds the 'Update' tab to the node path
 );

 $items['node/%node/update/price'] = array(
   'title' => 'Price',
   'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
   'weight' => -10
 );

 $items['node/%node/update/photo'] = array(
   'title' => 'Photo',
   'page callback' => 'callback_function',
   'access arguments' => array('access args'),
   'access callback' => TRUE,
   'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK // This adds another tab under 'Update'
 );
  return $items;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_admin_paths().
 *
 * Show admin theme on the participants totals report.
 */
function secondary_tabs_admin_paths() {
  return array(
    'node/*/update' => TRUE,
  );
}
```

My goal is to create a sub-section where I can click through a few views within this secondary tab area.

Also, I was trying to add the Admin theme to the views as well.I have it in code but it doesn't seem to work.

Can someone guide me towards what I might be missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So, Basically I was trying to piece together a few views under one local task tab for a content admin. I finally figure out how to write a small module to create the structure and used views path and menu to point to the sub task items. See below.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function secondary_tabs_menu() {
  $items['node/%node/update'] = array(
   'title' => 'Update',
   'page callback' => 'price_callback_function',
   #'access arguments' => array(2),
   'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK // This adds the 'Update' tab to the node path
 );

 $items['node/%node/update/price'] = array(
   'title' => 'Price',
   'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
   'weight' => -10
 );

 $items['node/%node/update/test'] = array(
   'title' => 'Test',
   'page callback' => 'callback_function',
   #'access arguments' => array(2),
   'access callback' => TRUE,
   'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK // This adds another tab under 'Update'
 );
 $items['node/%node/update/test/test1'] = array(
   'title' => 'Test1',
   'page callback' => 'callback_function',
   #'access arguments' => array(2),
   'access callback' => TRUE,
   'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK // This adds another tab under 'Update'
 );
 $items['node/%node/update/test/test2'] = array(
   'title' => 'Test2',
   'page callback' => 'callback_function',
   #'access arguments' => array(2),
   'access callback' => TRUE,
   'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK // This adds another tab under 'Update'
 );

  return $items;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_admin_paths().
 *
 * Show admin theme on the participants totals report.
 */
function secondary_tabs_admin_paths() {
  return array(
    'node/*/update' => TRUE,
    'node/*/update/test' => TRUE,
    'node/*/update/test/test1' => TRUE,
    'node/*/update/test/test2' => TRUE,
  );
}
```

I also found out the best way to make those views show up within the admin theme. See hook_admin_path().